# How to get bash to stop escaping $ during tab completion?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have this on the command line:

```bash
ln -sf $PWD/wine-
```

and then I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete the filename.  In earlier versions of Ubuntu, this worked just fine to complete the `wine-` filename (and as a side-effect `$PWD` would be expanded at that time).  But now it turns it in to

```bash
ln -sf \$PWD/wine-
```

which isn't what I meant at all and doesn't complete anything as the file does not literally start with `$`.

How do I get completion back to the less broken behaviour?

`set` tells me these are my current settings:

```bash
BASHOPTS=checkwinsize:cmdhist:expand_aliases:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
```

Comment: If you are affected by this bug please consider voting under the following url (requires login):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/778627/+affectsmetoo

Comment: How can this still be a there in 2020? If it understands that it's a path variable so that it expands the filename (which it does for me) it should understand to not escape the `$` that makes it a path variable...

Comment: As of August 2020, this bug still exists in Ubuntu 20.04, bash 5.0-6ubuntu1.1.

Comment: "This" is several bugs/ behaviour changes across both Bash itself and `bash-completion`, and the specific patches that each Linux distributions carry for both of these...

Comment: It looks like in ubuntu 22.04, you need to remove or comment out the completion code at the bottom of ~/bashrc.  I then put my options in .bash_aliases.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I've found that [bash versions >= 4.2.29](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?id=16b2d7f4ea7aa2e52c697bc7f623bf791725f42b) have a new `direxpand` shopt setting. (See `man docs/bash.1` if you check out a new bash, or see [bash.1 from line 8951](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/doc/bash.1?id=16b2d7f4ea7aa2e52c697bc7f623bf791725f42b))

If one uses Quantal Quetzal 12.10 or otherwise gets hold of (or checks out and builds) a new bash, then:

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

Gives me the behavior I want, need and love.

Workaround: In the meantime, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd> does what I want too. But is awkward.

BTW, There are several threads called "bash tab variable expansion question?" in [gnu.bash.bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/gnu.bash.bug). From reading them, I found the info here.

Comment: a version of bash with direxpand is making its way into Precise (12.04): See https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/778627

Comment: Would be even better if I didn't have my huge path expanded and could continue using an un-escaped variable with completion.

Comment: @jozxyqk Did you ever find a way to get that no-path-expansion feature?

Comment: @Ungeheuer I'm currently using bash `4.4.19` on Ubuntu 18.04 and it just works. Not sure when this changed.

Comment: user3080602's answer below worked for me - `shopt -u progcomp` solves the issue without expanding the variable to it's value

Comment: I don't know about Ubuntu, `direxpand` has its own [problems](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1782809) in Fedora.

Comment: The bad thing is that you have to re-set `direxpand` option in every new termnal.

Comment: I summarize the solution as following: 1- open `~/.bashrc` in an editor 2- add this line at the end of the file `shopt -s direxpand`. 3- save the file, close and open your terminal again; the problem is solved!

Comment: @jozxyqk Seems worth mentioning that this is exactly how `zsh` works out of the box. Seriously thinking of switching now.

Comment: @jozxyqk you write "I'm currently using bash 4.4.19 on Ubuntu 18.04 and it just works. Not sure when this changed" If you have the package `bash-completion` installed, it works because of an Ubuntu patch for this package, specifically [this one](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/tree/debian/patches/00-fix_quote_readline_by_ref.patch?h=applied/ubuntu/bionic)

Answer (score 42):

```
shopt -u progcomp
```

This fixed it for me, it also removed a lot of "intelligent" completion options which I have found get in the way by not completing files that I know are there because the stupid thing thinks I don't want them as arguments to a particular command. ARRRGH

Comment: This did it for me! It doesn't escape the variable, nor does it expand it. Thanks!

Comment: This (u)nsets the shell option `progcomp`. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) for more info.

Comment: This works for the paths, but for example  when using `make` seeing the make-targets is quite convenient, which is lost with this setting.

Comment: I also lost support for git tab-completion (e.g. `git checkout ` + Tab, for branch names). Otherwise, it was nice.

Answer (score 6):

search `_filedir()` in the top level bash_completion script and change the line

```
compopt -o filenames 2>/dev/null
```

to

```
compopt -o filenames -o noquote 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: In 12.04 GNU bash, version 4.2.25 this suggestion gives the error: `compopt: noquote: invalid option name`

Comment: To avoid changing the root-owned script, I'm using this in my .bash_profile: `eval $(type -a _filedir | tail -n +2 | sed 's/compopt -o filenames 2>/compopt -o filenames -o noquote 2>/')`

Comment: It now removes backslashes from manually-escaped filenames: `ls file\ w` [tab] → `ls file with space` where the expected result is `ls file\ with\ space`

Comment: In my comment above, the argument to `eval` should be quoted, and it can be simplified to `eval "$(declare -f _filedir | sed 's/compopt -o filenames 2>/compopt -o filenames -o noquote 2>/')"` (but this does indeed have the problem that iBug noted in the comment immediately above, so you need to say `ls "file w`[tab] to expand usefully).

Answer (score 5):

On GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release, the options `complete_fullquote` and `noquote` aren't available. The `cdable_vars` option works on `cd` only; `direxpand` expands the variable.

What worked best for me was:

```
shopt -u progcomp
```

It worked on other commands, besides `cd`, preserving the variables instead of expanding them.

Comment: Useless. It completely disables the intelligent completion from `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/` directory. So, now 99% of the things you will type manually.

Answer (score 2):

For those (like me) with 12.04 can use ~+ instead of $PWD...

for example :

```
cd /bin
echo ~+/ls
/bin/ls
```

Answer (score 1):

Even with the updated bash, I was finding `$` still gets escaped.

- Removing the `bash-completion (1:2.1-3.fc20)` package
- or simply not sourcing `/etc/bashrc` from `~/.bashrc` seemed to fix it.

I suspect I'll now be missing some features I'm normally used to but haven't noticed any yet.

---

Alternative (at least for Fedora 26), add `export BASH_COMPLETION_VERSINFO=0` before sourcing `/etc/bashrc`. This makes the problematic script think its already been sourced.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the shell option 'complete_fullquote' does the job:

```
shopt -u complete_fullquote
```

Comment: $ shopt -u complete_fullquote
-bash: shopt: complete_fullquote: invalid shell option name

Comment: The option is available for me in bash v5.0.17, but setting it results in undesirable behavior. When I tab-complete "vim ~/.ba" it adds a backslash like "vim \~/.bashrc", which seems similar to the issue OP had in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care for programmable completion (usually installed by `bash-completion`), then any method mentioned here to disable those will do (like `shopt -u progcomp`).

If you want Bash to expand the variable when you type TAB, then `shopt -s direxpand` will do.

If you do **not** want to use `shopt -s direxpand`, and want to **keep** programmable completions from `bash-completion`, and you have root access, you can apply the same patch as Ubuntu applies, i.e. [this patch](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash-completion/tree/debian/patches/00-fix_quote_readline_by_ref.patch?h=applied/ubuntu/bionic).

If you do not have root access you can disable the system `bash-completion` (see bash-completion's [README](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/#installation) and install a patched version in your `$HOME` (download and extract the tarball and `--configure --prefix=$HOME` or similar)

**EDIT** the above is valid for Bash 4.4.19. It seems Bash 5.0 and above break the whole thing again...

Comment: Is this Ubuntu patch coming to newer version of Ubuntu?