# How to downgrade a package via apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management, downgrade, versions

How can I downgrade a package to an older version via `apt-get`?

Other tools are also acceptable but `apt-get` is preferred.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Use:

```
apt-get install «pkg»=«version»
```

or:

```
sudo aptitude install «pkg»=«version»
```

Where:

- `«pkg»` is the name of the package.
- `«version»` is the version number.

Comment: when i type `apt-get install pkg=version` apt-get offers removing almost half of all installed packages which of course not what i want to do

Comment: As pointed in the (otherwise identical) answer with more votes, this seems to be one of the key cases where `aptitude` does a much better job than `apt-get`.  In my case `apt-get`flatly refused the downgrade request, whereas `aptitude` pointed out that there were other pkgs which depended on the newer version (and thus needed downgrading at the same time).

Comment: Hint: run `apt list -a <pkg>` to find out what versions are available

Answer (score 411):

If you have the version number, or the target release,  `apt-get` supports choosing a particular version or target release. More details can be found on [manual page of apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man8/apt-get.8.html). It can also be accessed from terminal by typing `man apt-get`

`sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>`  OR

`sudo apt-get -t=<target release> install <package-name>`

is the command to be run. This can be used to down-grade a package to a specific version.

Remark that when using a target release (option `-t`), the release priority must greater than 1000 to allow downgrades (see [`man 5 apt_preferences`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html)) otherwise the currently installed version will be kept.

It has been helpfully pointed out in the comments that

- `apt-cache showpkg <package-name>` lists all available versions. (h/t [Sparhawk](https://askubuntu.com/users/53508/sparhawk))
- `apt-mark hold <package-name>`  "holds" the package at the current version, preventing automatic upgrades. (h/t [Luís de Sousa](https://askubuntu.com/users/177437/lu%c3%ads-de-sousa) )

Comment: I found that `aptitude` downgraded the dependencies better than `apt-get`.

Comment: `apt-cache policy <package-name>` shows just the installed and available versions

Comment: And what if `showpkg` does not show the version you are interested in?

Comment: @demongolem Based on [jozxyqk comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/136633/759533), I want to downgrade my `bash` to `4.4.18-2ubuntu1`; both `aptitude` and `apt-get` refuse to do so as they two believe that there is no such a version. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Note that you may need to pass `--allow-downgrades` if doing this with `-y`

Answer (score 39):

If you have upgraded software using ppa you can downgrade it by using `ppa-purge`. First you have to install `ppa-purge` using this code:

> sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

Then you can remove the ppa using command

> sudo ppa-purge ppa:user/ppa-name

this will automatically downgrade the software to its original version which shipped with Ubuntu.

Comment: This solution is just unmatched in case the package has dependencies which also have to be downgraded. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is the solution that worked best for me for downgrading KDE/Plasma desktop from kubuntu-ppa/backports - one thing I noticed is the PPA's .list file must not have the deb commented out, so ppa-purge can reference all the files that need to be removed for the purge.  Took me a minute to figure out why it wasn't working at first.  Hope that helps other people!

Answer (score 16):

In my opinion, you should first uninstall or purge the package, like:

```
sudo apt-get remove <package>
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge <package>
```

Then, you may download the version you would like to install and keep it in a folder, say `abc.deb` in Downloads. Open terminal, move to the folder using `cd` command and install the previous version using `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i abc.deb
```

Or else, there is a small utility called `ppa-purge` if you mean to downgrade packages updated via PPAs.

See this thread: http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/remove-ppa-repositories-via-command.html

Comment: removing a package may remove many dependent ones, resulting in an unusable system. ppapurge sounds interesting though.

Comment: Can  you explain *why* you believe we ought to first uninstall packages (as a separate step) before installing older versions of them?

Comment: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.puppet.devel/23219

Comment: @temoto that link is for downgrading releases `unstable` -> `testing` -> `stable` not to downgrade individual packages.

Answer (score 15):

To downgrade you have to do a command like

```
 sudo apt-get install pkg_name=version
```

in your terminal.

In the place of `version` put the previous version you want to downgrade to.

Comment: It doesn't work at least for linux-generic which depends on packages that should be downgraded too. I get https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NWSmf2ZwTy/

Comment: Some depending packages may have to be purged before installing a specific version of the desired package...

Comment: @mymedia `linux-generic` is a meta package, not a package. Kernel packages in ubuntu always have a version as part of the package like `linux-image-5.15.0-100-generic` with version `5.15.0-100.110~20.04.1` i.e. `linux-image-5.15.0-100-generic-5.15.0-100.110~20.04.1`. So kernel packages are never updates, but independently named packages. This allows for multiple versions of the kernel to be installed together. It also ***doesn't break the system by removing mods of the running kernel*** . Your issue is that you tried installing separate kernel packages with conflicting dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

This question is old but Google led me here and I didn't find simple solution that does't require manual version passing when downgrading a bunch of packages to an older release.

So maybe someone who also needs that will find my solution useful as well.

There's a tool called `apt-show-versions` that shows versions installed. To install it:

```
$ sudo apt install apt-show-versions
```

Make sure APT's cache is up to date:

```
$ sudo apt-show-versions -i
```

You can easily downgrade all required packages by fine-tuning the regex but here it is:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get install $(apt-show-versions \
   | grep -P 'newer than version in archive' \
   | awk -F: '{print $1"/'$(lsb_release -cs)'"}')
```

You should have `lsb-release` installed for the latter.

Comment: Or automatically downgrade to up-to-date installed release: `sudo apt-get install -V $(apt-show-versions | grep -F 'newer than version in archive' | awk -F: '{print $1"/'$(lsb_release -cs)'"}')`. I prefer using `-F` for `grep` here.

Comment: Thank you, this is incredibly helpful!

Comment: @jarno thanks for the incantation; I adjusted it to work for packages that come in multiple arch flavors on the same platform (e.g. libc6): `sudo apt-get install -V $(apt-show-versions | grep -F 'newer than version in archive' | awk -F' ' '{print $1"/'$(lsb_release -cs)'"}')` (just change the separator for awk from colon to space).