# Installing a previous version of a package when you don't have the .deb available?

Tags: apt, versions

Same question as [how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get), except what if it's on a newly deployed server and the archived `.deb` is not there?

For example, https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/wget tells me the previous version is `1.13.4-1ubuntu2`, and I have `1.13.4-2ubuntu` installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep wget
ii  wget                            1.13.4-2ubuntu1            retrieves files from the web
```

When I try to force the version:

```
vagrant@es2:~$ sudo apt-get install wget=1.13.4-1ubuntu2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.13.4-1ubuntu2' for 'wget' was not found
```

Is there a way to "ask" `apt-get update` to fetch information/URLs/etc. about older versions?

Is the solution to run my own apt repository with the versions I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/85655688/wget_1.13.4-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

result

```
--08:29:45--  http://launchpadlibrarian.net/85655688/wget_1.13.4-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
           => `wget_1.13.4-1ubuntu2_i386.deb'
Resolving launchpadlibrarian.net... 91.189.89.229, 91.189.89.228
Connecting to launchpadlibrarian.net|91.189.89.229|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 282,988 (276K) [application/x-debian-package]

100%[====================================================>] 282,988      445.03K/s

08:29:46 (443.76 KB/s) - `wget_1.13.4-1ubuntu2_i386.deb' saved [282988/282988]
```

As long as you have an internet connection you can wget all the debs you want. After this you can try to install it with USC (might not work due to dependencies) or with `dpkg` but you might need to wget the dependencies 1st too.

In this case wget ...

> Package relationships. Depends on

```
dpkg (>= 1.15.4)
libc6 (>= 2.11)
libidn11 (>= 1.13)
libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0)
```

> Package relationships. Conflicts

```
wget-ssl
```

---

By the way: I searched https://launchpad.net for `wget 1.13.4-1ubuntu2` and use the link on this page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/wget/1.13.4-1ubuntu2 to locally download the file named `wget_1.13.4-1ubuntu2_i386.deb (276.4 KiB)`.

In theory you can create the download from memory for other files.