# texinfo downgrade

Tags: downgrade, patch

Can anyone help me with downgrading a texinfo package from version > 5 to 4.13? This version comes with ubuntu 13.04 or higher and I urgently need 4.13 version. I've found this .patch files but don't have any clue how to install/implement it.

[thread](https://dev.openwrt.org/ticket/13039)

[patch](http://patchwork.openwrt.org/patch/3605/)

Comment: I will recommend to check this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get

Comment: It's not difficult to compile and install texinfo. Use `configure` with a `--prefix`. That's what I did after a bit of head-bashing-on-the-wall for compiling GCC.

Comment: Yeah, I've already tried via apt-get, but no luck. I'll try configure..

Answer (score 2):

The instructions for installing GNU Texinfo from the [GNU Texinfo](http://petio.org/tools/texinfo.html) website worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Remove the current texinfo via apt-get (I'm not sure if this is required, but I did it just to be safe).
2. Download the texinfo source:

   ```
   wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/texinfo-4.13.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract the source files:

   ```
   gzip -dc < texinfo-4.13.tar.gz | tar -xf -
   cd texinfo-4.13
   ```
4. Configure, build and install:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

On my computer I also had to install libncurses before I could successfully build texinfo.

Comment: IMO it's worth mentioning that `texi2dvi` doesn't seem to work on modern machines. At least i had an issue on my Ubuntu trusty. The problem is, that in that shell script `local` is used as a name for a function. Solution can be found [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=619786#5)