# how to downgrade related packages together?

Tags: apt, package-management, downgrade

[Related Question : downgrade a package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get)

The situation is a bit different, I have a group of packages say aaa-*.deb which was involved in the down grade. obviously I don't want to deal with them one by one.

when update these packages to the latest: a repository is set through:

```
deb http://unity-3.dev.net/ $VERSION
```

and then aptitude pull all these packages and renew them on the system. while in the case of the downgrade, they simply won't get updated.

I've seen the related question, but deal with them one-by-one is really tedious and un-desired, so is there a way to make the apt-get to pull all these debian files and update them again.