# I need to install numpy 1.8.1 for ubuntu 14.04 (downgrade from 1.8.2)

Tags: 14.04

my ubuntu is 14.04. I need to install numpy 1.8.1. Where can I find its directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`. The version in 14.04 is 1.8.2 (it was updated from 1.8.1 --- so probably you want to stick with the new one; it's a stable release update so it surely fixes bugs).

If you want to stick with the older version due to a verification script (which is not recommended; that script is not very well thought) you can do that; install it with the suggestion here: [How to Downgrade a Package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get) and then mark it "held" with `apt mark hold python-numpy`. Basically it should be (**not tested**)

```
sudo apt-get install  python-numpy=1:1.8.1-1ubuntu1
sudo apt-mark hold python-numpy
```

...but I would fix the script instead. Holding packages can have a lot of nasty consequences on the long run.

The available versions can be found with `apt-cache search numpy` and after finding the correct name (by looking at the list):

```
[romano:~] % apt-cache policy python-numpy
python-numpy:
  Installed: 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.8.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: this is 1.8.2 version but I need to get 1.8.1 beacuse the verification script requires 1.8.1