# How to force apt-get to skip a package version

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, downgrade

There is an excellent [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get) on how to downgrade a package, but I would like to know how to force apt-get and Software Updater to skip a version.

For example, the current release of Firefox is 36.0. This particular build is broken in that it cannot open external urls. I've had to downgrade to version 28.0, but Software Updater is now prompting me to update back to 36.0. I would like to skip this version and upgrade to the next which I'm sure will be fixed.

Comment: See if this helps http://askubuntu.com/a/322945/33871

Comment: @Salem Thanks for the link. I think putting the package on hold and manually checking it's status may be the best way.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to "Pin" the package to the version you want. See [the official Pinning Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto).