# How to fix wrong update?

Tags: updates, ftp, tls

Today I updated my Ubuntu 15.04 using the auto update tool. Here are the updated packages:

- firefox-locales (40.0+build4-0ubuntu0.15.01.1, 40.0+build4-ubuntu0.15.04.4)
- firefox (40.0+build4-0ubuntu0.15.04.1, 40.0+build4-0ubuntu0.15.04.4)
- openssh-server (6.7p1-5ubuntu1.2, 6.7p1-5ubuntu1.3)
- openssh-sftp-server(6.7p1-5ubuntu1.2, 6.7p1-5ubuntu1.3)
- ssh-askpass-gnome (6.7p1-5ubuntu1.2, 6.7p1-5ubuntu1.3)
- ssh (6.7p1-5ubuntu1.2, 6.7p1-5ubuntu1.3)
- openssh-client (6.7p1-5ubuntu1.2, 6.7p1-5ubuntu1.3)

Unfortunatly, after this update I cannot connect to my FTP server over TLS anymore :/

Is there a way to cancel this update?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Downgrade a Package via apt-get?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get)

Comment: This does not help me about which version number to downgrade to.

Comment: Actually, you need to upgrade your client as there have been security vulnerabilities uncovered on lower-version TLS...  Have a look here https://www.howsmyssl.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found how to update my FTP client (FileZilla) to the almost last version :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove filezilla
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get -t=<target release> install <package-name>
```

already asked in the forum for example in

[How to Downgrade a Package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get)

Comment: OK thanks but I'm not sure about what is the `package-version-number`. Is it something like `6.7p1-5ubuntu1.3` ? It doesn't work with it.

Comment: Please don't link to copies of other answers but flag them as duplicate...