# Problem installing uuid-dev

Tags: server, apt, package-management

```
$ sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 uuid-dev : Depends: libuuid1 (= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` then try.  I think you maybe have out of date repository information.

Comment: i make update and still get same problem

Comment: Any error messages after `apt-get update`? Please post them. Either way proceed to a full update with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Again, if you notice error messages post them.

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
 i have the same error for multibul files

Answer (score 2):

You need downgrade your `libuuid1` version from 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1 to 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.

You can use `apt-get` to do a downgrade, refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get).

`sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>` OR
`sudo apt-get -t=<target release> install <package-name>`

If you are using `synaptic` package manager, you can also just simply select the package (in your case, search and select `libuuid1`), and go to menu **Package > Force Version..** to choose the version you would like to install, then click **Apply**.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command and try again

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: still same error
amanyubntu@amanyubntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.