# Installing Octave 4.0.2 with apt-get

Tags: apt, octave

I am trying to install Octave 4.0.2 (specifically that version; I have reason to believe there is an incompatibility that affects software I want to run with and would like to install this version to verify or invalidate that claim) with apt-get.

As detailed [here](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable), I have run the following, seemingly without error

```
add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
apt-get update
```

(Sudo is not necessary, this is within a docker)

However, following up with:

```
apt-get install octave=4.0.2
```

as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get) simply gives me a version not found error:

```
Version '4.0.2' for 'octave' was not found
```

Likewise for variations on that package name up to and including the full expression of '4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~precise2'

Curiously I can install (and uninstall) the latest version of Octave, v4.2.1.

What am I missing?  How can I get the necessary version installed?

**UPDATE 1**  The Ubuntu version, internal to the docker, is 16.04.3 LTS

**UPDATE 2**  The results of

```
apt-cache policy octave
```

are:

```
 Installed: 4.2.1-2~octave~xenial1
  Candidate: 4.2.1-2~octave~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 4.2.1-2~octave~xenial1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/octave/stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.0.0-3ubuntu9.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     4.0.0-3ubuntu9 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

That is with a later version of Octave presently installed.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: can you post the output of `apt-cache policy octave`?

Comment: @N0rbert see update above:  16.04.3

Comment: @ravery see update above

Comment: From apt-cache policy we can conclude that there is no octave 4.0.2 version.

Comment: But for example [zesty (17.04) has 4.0.3-3ubuntu1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=octave).

Comment: v4.0.2 isn't available in the repositories that you currently have in your sources.list. "4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~precise2'" check the precise repository. Though, you may have dependency problems going that far back.

Comment: Ahh, I see the problem, now.  The 4.0.2 I thought existed is not for Xenial, but for Precise.

Comment: I see two solutions: 1. install octave from source on xenial; 2. install Precise into docker, then add PPA with 4.0.2 here (**insecure solution**).