# cURL not Working after 18.04 Upgrade

Tags: php, nginx, curl

I recently updated the system to 18.04 and it has hosed cURL. 18.04 installed PHP 7.2 but my nginx installation is using 7.1 FPM. When I run a phpinfo() from the web server, it shows the system reading a curl.ini, but the cURL module is not shown below, and code that requires cURL doesn't work.

I've read this [**curl** is not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029273/curl-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts) and the answer (uninstall/reinstall libcurl4) didn't help.

I've done "phpenmod -v 7.1 curl", the module shows in the "enabled_by_admin" directory. There wasn't a curl.so but I copied it out of the 7.2 directory. Restarted, rebooted, everything. Still no cURL.

When I do "php -m" it shows curl, but that's for v7.2 of course, not the 7.1 FPM that my web server is running. I've been chasing my tail trying to get this running again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I gave up and simply converted all 12 sites that I'm running to use 7.2. Turns out it was easier than trying to stay on 7.1.

I updated the default 7.2 installation to contain all the components I needed (including FPM and many others), then edited each site's nginx.conf to reference 7.2 and it's all working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Search NGINX config. Instructions: https://devanswers.co/nginx-config-file-location/
2. Find in conf file "**fastcgi_pass**" which php version is used as fpm. Example for unix socket connection `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;` In this case you can understood that we deal with php 7.2 and ofcourse with modules installed in php 7.2.
3. Looks like you have a different version php installed on your system. Different version of php means different configs (php.ini) and different modules (including **curl**). Choose which php you want use. In your case if you continue using 7.2 then you need install znd configure curl module for it. If php 7.1 already have and wokr with curl and you not need 7.2 you need switch to 7.1 in NGINX conf. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass
4. Find socket path to php 7.1 in php conf (php.ini). Example: `isten = /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock` Check if it exist: `ls -lah /run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock`
5. Replace socket path in **fastcgi_pass** in NGINX conf. For example `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;` (In some case can be setup with host:IP. Need your choice, what is better for you: unix socket or host. In this tutorial i talk about socket)
6. Restart NGINX:    `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: Thank you, but I didn't really want or care about 7.2. It just got installed for me by the 18.04 upgrade. The server is doing fine with 7.1. What I'm trying to figure out is how to get cURL working for the 7.1

In addition, 7.1 PHP is working just fine. The _only_ thing I can't get working is cURL on the 7.1 FPM. Thx

Comment: 1) You told curl is still work with php 7.1. Right?
2) In your case in web-browser phpinfo() you see php 7.2? Right?
If 1 and 2 correct then you need switch which php listen NGINX. I wrote above how you can do it.

Comment: Or try reinstall curl for 7.1: try `sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl` or `sudo apt-get install php-curl` and restart php-fpm.

Comment: No, you have it backwards. My phpinfo() from the web server shows 7.1 (and no cURL). My command line shows 7.2.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Try `sudo apt install php7.1-curl` and `sudo service php-fpm restart`

Comment: When I try to install 7.1 `sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl` I get `Package php7.1-curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source`

Comment: I can't check it, but you can try install it from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/amd64/php7.1-curl/download