# `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by curl)

Tags: curl

i am trying to use curl and

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"items":[{"name":"first order","id":42}]}' http://localhost:8080/create-order
```

responds with

```
curl: /home/sara/LD_LIBRARY/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by curl)
```

followed the solution given (here)[[curl is not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029273/curl-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts]) but no luck

Answer (score 3):

Run this command : `locate libcurl.so.4`
Result will be :

1. /YOUR_PATH/libcurl.so.4 (generally the path is "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4")
2. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.5.0

Remove the file which is causing the error using
`sudo rm /YOUR_PATH/libcurl.so.4` command.

Recreate softlink by using following command :
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.5.0 /YOUR_PATH/libcurl.so.4`