# curl: /home/user/LD_LIBRARY/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by curl)

Tags: curl, openssl

i am using ubuntu 18.04 LTS and my kernel version is `4.15.0-96-generic` i have installed curl via

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

when i am using command `curl --version` it says

```
curl: /home/user/LD_LIBRARY/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by curl)
```

i have gone over this link [curl is not working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029273/curl-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts)
but it did not resolved the error

where `openssl version`
returns

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any software installed from official repository should simply work out the box without exceptions. The curl is essential component, so you have broke it.

Please check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and/or remove problematic library from home-folder by

```
rm /home/user/LD_LIBRARY/libcurl.so.4
```

Comment: after that i am getting -> curl: libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by curl)

Comment: after removing it from the home folder and from .bashrc it worked thanks