# Prevent system of using updates after downloading and updating them

Tags: updates, 17.10

I accidentally downloaded updates (I was typing when the pop-up that new updates are available was displayed and apparently put in focus).
I did not manage to cancel the Software Updater, it is now grayed out and displaying "Please restart the computer to begin using your updated software".

Is there a way to reverse the update?
Can I have it not come in effect until a date I specify?
Can I just not restart my computer? (or will ubuntu do that anyways after some time?)

Comment: Why have you used the `17.10` tag? Is that the version of your system?

Comment: 17.10 has gone end of life so we do not support it anymore Please plan a reinstall to install 18.04 And why not just reboot?

Comment: @DKBose Yes, it is. Should I include it int he text of the post?

Comment: @Rinzwind I am worried that _if_ something goes wrong I lose some important work; i dont want to lose time getting the backup. I plan to update to 19.04 as soon as i hand in my work.

Comment: How to do so: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get. Downgrading is *possible* but  *unsupported*, so yes you should be worried about data loss and other unexpected consequences.

Comment: If the work is important, immediately make a backup, then apply the update. The chance that the update breaks your system is extremely slim (not so for Arch users ;) )

Comment: @Anushka--x so you make a backup.

Answer (score 2):

Reversing an update in Ubuntu may or may not be a trivial task. The update is now installed, and still needs some configuration on a next reboot. I recommend to reboot the computer and have the update installed. Updates that come through the software center are quite reliable and tested, and may bring significant security improvements. They will, by design of the Ubuntu release schedule, never cause your system to function differently.

Comment: Never? *sobs into beer*