# Password failed error when connecting via xrdp (MATE desktop) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xrdp

This error happens despite entering the correct password.

[image: connection log]

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling xrdp and Mate but still getting the same error. It used to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, there was a newer version rdp installed on my system via updates.  If you can roll back to the older version that should fix the problem.

I however found what I think is a better solution here:
https://netdevops.me/2017/installing-xrdp-0.9.1-on-ubuntu-16.04-xenial/

There was another fix reported here:
[xrdp failed (problem connecting) when package was auto-updated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108550/xrdp-failed-problem-connecting-when-package-was-auto-updated)

good luck

Comment: Downgrading worked!! Thanks so much, I was bashing my head against the wall for 2 days trying to fix this. I actually restored the server to an older date to get it working again. Unfortunately I couldn't get the newer version to work with the other solution you provided.