# How to freeze a list of installed packages and craft an apt-upgrade script to target the same at any time after?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

In a LXC container I want be able to note the packages I've just updated to then recreate that situation any date after that.

I think I want to do something like:

```
dpkg-query --show | sed "s/\t/=/" > somewhere_safe.txt
```

That'd give a list like:

```
adduser=3.118
apache2=2.4.38-3+deb10u4
apache2-bin=2.4.38-3+deb10u4
apache2-data=2.4.38-3+deb10u4
apache2-utils=2.4.38-3+deb10u4
apparmor=2.13.2-10
apt=1.8.2.1
apt-listchanges=3.19
apt-transport-https=1.8.2.1
apt-utils=1.8.2.1
# and so on
```

Then post process that with an `apt upgrade` script that takes them all as arguments. Am I going about this the right way?

Rationale: `apt update` doesn't have an "as of this date" argument, meaning I couldn't recreate something if I wanted to, yet I generally speaking want something recreatable in respect of packages even if I'm not using docker-style image repositories.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt list --installed | sed s/Listing...// | awk -F "/" '{print $1}' >  $(date +aptlist-%m.%d.%Y-%H.%M.%S.txt)
```

Creates the file which lists all of the installed packages.

```
xargs -a ThatFileCratedAbove.txt sudo apt-get install
```

Will install them from the list

....I would test the file first with `apt-get -s install` to simulate installation, just to make sure the list is not going to cause any problems.. (though that might take a long time)

.
.
.

**UPDATE FOR  VERSION REQUIREMENT...**
If you wanted to capture the version and be able to install those versions later, then your apt list snapshot would need to be created like this instead of above:

```
apt list --installed | sed s/Listing...// | awk -F"[[:blank:]/]" '{ if( $1 ne '' ) print $1"="$3}' >  $(date +aptlist-%m.%d.%Y-%H.%M.%S.txt)
```

Comment: That creates a list like "adduser\n
apache2-bin\n
apache2-data\n
apache2-utils\n
apache2\n
apparmor\n
apt-listchanges\n
apt-transport-https\n
apt-utils\n
apt\n
attr" for me. There's no timestamp, hash or versionNum in there, so I'm not sure how I would update to anything other than "latest" if I ran it six months from now.

Comment: the filename is the timestamp... But I see... you also want a version snapshot?

Comment: yup, that's the idea

Comment: then you were basically already there... as long as there were no additional header lines in your dpkg output.

Comment: Close. If I take the somewhere_safe.txt list I had and xargs it into params for apt-get install as you have it it works great. One more test - I edit the list to change "adduser" from 3.118 to 3.116 and it barfs: E: Version '3.116' for 'adduser' was not found. It is possible that was never in the DebianBuster package list. I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the list.. that's apt telling you it just doesn't exist

Comment: Yup https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get goes further. Find "no such a version" in page. My test is `apt-cache showpkg cargo` not showing any history of cargo before Debian 10.6.

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79050/can-i-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade-if-something-goes-wrong has a "It may no longer be in the repository" claim, which makes me think this is impossible via 'apt' today.