# Roll back Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, crash, restore, automatic

Has anyone ever actually rolled back an upgrade? The upgrades installed 07-07-2021

```
Upgrade: avahi-autoipd:amd64 (0.8-5ubuntu3, 0.8-5ubuntu3.1), avahi-utils:amd64 (0.8-5ubuntu3, 0.8-5ubuntu3.1), libavahi-common-data:amd64 (0.8-5ubuntu3, 0.8-5ubuntu3.1), libavahi-core7:amd64 (0.8-5ubuntu3, 0.8->
End-Date: 2021-07-07  23:55:17
Upgrade: linux-base:amd64 (4.5ubuntu5.2, 4.5ubuntu5.3)
End-Date: 2021-07-06  14:39:25
```

One of these destroyed my bluetooth connection. How do I un-upgrade the "linux base amd64" upgrade for example?

Comment: You'd likely do better without the *foul* language; it made me lose interest for one (as well as telling us your OS & release details instead of us needing to look up that detail from what you've provided)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade a package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get)