# SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches | New release of CURL(USN-6237-1) brings suffering

Tags: 22.04, ssl, curl

Since new release of CURL https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6237-1 we experianc problem with curl command on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt install --no-install-recommends -y curl
curl -vvv https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.8.8/binaries/
```

Error:

```
*   Trying 88.99.95.219:443...
99
* Connected to downloads.apache.org (88.99.95.219) port 443 (#0)
100
* ALPN, offering h2
101
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
102
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
103
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
104
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
105
} [5 bytes data]
106
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
107
} [512 bytes data]
108
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
109
{ [5 bytes data]
110
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
111
{ [122 bytes data]
112
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
113
{ [5 bytes data]
114
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
115
{ [5 bytes data]
116
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
117
{ [25 bytes data]
118
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
119
{ [5 bytes data]
120
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
121
{ [4583 bytes data]
122
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
123
{ [5 bytes data]
124
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
125
{ [264 bytes data]
126
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
127
{ [5 bytes data]
128
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
129
{ [52 bytes data]
130
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
131
} [5 bytes data]
132
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
133
} [1 bytes data]
134
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
135
} [5 bytes data]
136
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
137
} [52 bytes data]
138
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
139
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
140
* Server certificate:
141
*  subject: CN=*.apache.org
142
*  start date: Jun 29 00:00:00 2022 GMT
143
*  expire date: Jul 30 23:59:59 2023 GMT
144
*  subjectAltName does not match downloads.apache.org
145
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'downloads.apache.org'
146
* Closing connection 0
147
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
148
} [5 bytes data]
149
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
150
} [2 bytes data]
151
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'downloads.apache.org'
152
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

How to fix it? Should we since now control 3rd party certs somehow?Worked yesterday.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

Look like there was a broken backport for a security fix. Should be fixed in 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.13 which fixes 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.11. From https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/curl/+changelog:

```
curl (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.13) jammy-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY REGRESSION: broken ssl cert wildcard handling (LP: #2028170)
    - debian/patches/CVE-2023-28321.patch: fix missing line in backport.

 -- Marc Deslauriers <email address hidden>  Wed, 19 Jul 2023 12:23:36 -0400
curl (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.11) jammy-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: improper certificate validation vulnerability
    - debian/patches/CVE-2023-28321.patch: fix host name wildcard checking
      in lib/hostcheck.c, tests/data/test1397, tests/unit/unit1397.c.
    - CVE-2023-28321
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Methods to get to the older version:

Remove it and use `apt` to install the previous version. Here is the most active topic on AU on this: [How to downgrade a package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get) It is also possible to [install from source](https://curl.se/docs/install.html). That might be a better method: you can leave the apt version as is, wait for an update/bug fix and try the new one alongside the source install version.

Check if any of these fixes your issue. If so file a bug report. If you want to stick to the older apt version [pin](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) the package

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind!
we did just that, downgraded the version of the curl and the library. That helped. But the bottom line is that this is a crutch. I hope the fix doesn't take too long.

Comment: @Rinzwind: there seems to be a newly introduced bug in the code validating the certificate subject alternative names, while trying to fixing a bug there.  So using a different CA certificates will not help. The bug happens for me too.

Comment: Oh thanks saves me searching :D (because I am likely to face this at work in a few days too :D )

Comment: Yeah... but it doesn't work for me as of today. Yesterday there was a new release. I'll try to open a bug ticket.

Comment: @SergeiVaraksin: no need, the bug is already known and fixed in the latest update. I'll  create an answer

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ooo, great! Thanks) Will wait

Answer (score 4):

This is a confirmed bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/2028170

They have already fixed it by reverting the changes and the new package version will be live soon.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Will fill a bug report in the corresponding resources next time.