# Curl errors on fresh 22.04 install

Tags: curl

Fresh install of 22.04 curl works very sporadically when attempting to access secure sites. Sometimes it works but most times I get either an error 35 or 60.  Installed our company root and intermediate certificates, installed a cert from a Trusted Authority, but no luck. Doing the same from my home network works just fine.  Assuming it's some kind of certificate issue but all our certs are installed. Updated ca-certificates, etc.  No proxy here.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Are you on VPN? Why don't you include the output in your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches | New release of CURL(USN-6237-1) brings suffering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478616/ssl-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches-new-release-of-curlusn-6)