# How to force apt/apt-get to update to latest version on package server without specifying the version?

Tags: apt, package-management

How do I force apt/apt-get to update to the latest version of a package that is available on the package server even if this means a downgrade but without specifying the version I want to install.

For example I have `foo_0.2` locally installed and the server only has `foo_0.1`. In that case I want to get `foo_0.1` installed.

I know I can manually find out the version available on the package server via `apt policy foo` and then run `apt install foo=0.1`.
But is there a command that just installs the latest version that is on the package server without me explicitly specifying the version?

Note: A similar question was asked in [How to downgrade a package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get), but this question here is about downgrading without manually specifying a version.

Comment: similar question was already answered https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get
[answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1112347/1180244)

Comment: Is it better to ask the question like this? _How can I get a list of all packages that are installed on my system and are with a higher version than the ones available on the package server_?

Comment: @mipolak Not exactly I don't want to specify the version to install. I edited my question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: @FedKad Good idea, but in this case not really as I already know the package I want to downgrade/update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `apt_preferences` to accomplish this.

For example, if the "package server" containing the `foo` package is `archive.ubuntu.com` then you can configure a preference for this server

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/preferences.d/50my
Package: *
Pin: origin archive.ubuntu.com
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF
```

The `Pin-Priority` value must be `1000` or higher.  From the [apt_preferences man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html)

> ```
>    P >= 1000
>        causes a version to be installed even if this constitutes a downgrade of the package
> ```

If you were to run `apt-get install foo` then the `foo` package should be downgraded without having to specify the specific version.

I have not tested this setup to verify it works.

Comment: Thank you. I tested it and it is exactly what I asked for.

Comment: This is great answer that deserves more upvotes.