# How to disable automatic backslash insert when using environment variable names on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS terminal(s)

Tags: command-line, bash, 20.04, environment-variables

When I use environment variable name and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> for auto-complete on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS terminal (I have tested both the terminal which comes with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS install and Terminator, same behavior on both), Ubuntu inserts backslash \ before dollar sign $, causing the environment variable not to work anymore as intended.

For example, previously on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS terminal:

```
ll $HOME/Deskt (+TAB) -> ll $HOME/Desktop/
```

Now on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS terminal:

```
ll $HOME/Deskt (+TAB) -> ll \$HOME/Desktop/
```

Needless to say, the latter results in

```
ls: cannot access '$HOME/Desktop/': No such file or directory
```

So how can I disable the automatic `\` insert?

Comment: This appears to be a bug: [#653837
bash-completion: Variable $HOME in paths is escaped](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=653837) and upstream [Completion of valid paths involving variables adds backslashes #290](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues/290)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get bash to stop escaping $ during tab completion?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70750/how-to-get-bash-to-stop-escaping-during-tab-completion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

then run this command to apply the changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```