# Bash doesn't expand variables when pressing Tab key

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

In the previous versions of Ubuntu 18.04, the variables in Bash are expanded when I press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. But in Ubuntu 20.04 (using bash 5.0.16), the variables are not expanded. Instead, the dollar sign `$` before the variable gets proceeded by a backslash.

For example, let's say, I have a variable `MY_DIRECTORY`:

```bsh
export MY_DIRECTORY=/path/to/a/folder
```

Now when I write something like this:

```bsh
ls $MY_DIRECTORY<Tab key>
```

I get:

```bsh
ls \$MY_DIRECTORY
```

As you can see, the variable doesn't expand to the desired path. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Similar question yesterday: [How to disable automatic backslash insert when using environment variable names on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS terminal(s)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245016/how-to-disable-automatic-backslash-insert-when-using-environment-variable-names)

Comment: Why do you want it to be expanded to a path ? It would work even without expansion.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi: because that breaks autocompletion for paths that are given as variables.

Comment: It looks like this was also answered 10 years ago:  [How to get bash to stop escaping $ during tab completion?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70750/how-to-get-bash-to-stop-escaping-during-tab-completion)

Comment: It could not be answered 10 years ago if the OP is noticing the behaviour changed between Ubuntu 18 and 20 ;). Yes the issue is the same, but the cause it not the same as 10 years ago. It depends on the specific versions of Bash, `bash-completion` and the specific patches that each Linux distribution apply to both of these.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have the following two options for expanding a variable in Bash:

- Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> keyboard shortcut whenever you want to expand a variable.

  For example, if I write in my terminal:

  ```
  $LANG $BASH
  ```

  and then press the shortcut, the above will expand both variables to:

  ```
  en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/bash
  ```
- Enable the [`shopt` builtin's](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) `direxpand` option by running in your terminal:

  ```
  shopt -s direxpand
  ```

  Now, if you type:

  ```
  ls $MY_DIRECTORY/<Tab key>
  ```

  it will be expanded to:

  ```
  ls /path/to/a/folder/
  ```

  To have the `direxpand` option enabled for all terminal sessions, append `shopt -s direxpand` in your `~/.bashrc` file either manually or by running:

  ```
  echo "shopt -s direxpand" >> ~/.bashrc
  ```