# TAB does't work properly with `cp` command when using environment variables

Tags: command-line, 20.04, environment-variables, cp, auto-completion

## Question

When using `cp` command with environment variables, why pressing `TAB` for auto-complete doesn't work properly?

## Description

I have a directory `$HOME/Music`; I want to copy a file from within this directory to the current directory. Therefore:

1. I Type `cp $HOM` and press TAB, so it reads `cp $HOME` ;
2. There is an additional space after `cp $HOME` , therefore I delete it by
   `Backspace` and then type a slash:`cp $HOME/`;
3. Now Press `TAB` creates `cp \$HOME/` which has a spurious `backslash` at the beginning of `$HOME`.
   When writing further letters i.e. `cp \$HOME/Mu` for Music, TAB doesn't
   work for autocompletion.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Think this may be relevant [How to get bash to stop escaping $ during tab completion?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70750/how-to-get-bash-to-stop-escaping-during-tab-completion)

Comment: Answer: Based on the comment above, the solution is as following: 1- open `~/.bashrc` in an editor 2- add this line at the end of the file `shopt -s direxpand`. 3- save the file, close and open your terminal again; the problem is solved!