# Why autocompletion in terminal converts $ENVAR to \$ENVAR? (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: command-line, 20.04, auto-completion

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.

When I pressed the tab key for auto-completion of an environment variable, let say ENVAR, which contains directory information, it suddenly converted the '$' to '$' so that I could not input the directory any longer.

i.e.,

`ENVAR=$HOME/mydir`

and I want to input `$ENVAR/subdir1`.
So I press the tab key at

`$ cd $ENVAR/sub`

then it returns

`$ cd \$ENVAR/subdir1`

What should I do?

Has anyone experienced a similar problem to me?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's normal behavior. Let it happen.

Comment: you can use `shopt -s direxpand` to get the old behavior back [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/136633/986805)

Comment: @user535733 Why is it better to let it happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get bash to stop escaping $ during tab completion?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70750/how-to-get-bash-to-stop-escaping-during-tab-completion)