# Tab autocomplete with environmental variables do not work

Tags: command-line, 20.04

Since I updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, autocomplete with environmental variables do not work. If I type:

```
ls $HOME<tab>
```

I get what I want, but if I add a `/`:

```
ls $HOME/<tab>
```

it autocomplete it to:

```
ls \$HOME/
```

Where it stops showing what it's on the folder. What can I do to stop this behavior?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get bash to stop escaping $ during tab completion?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70750/how-to-get-bash-to-stop-escaping-during-tab-completion)

Comment: I think it doesn't. I have a similar version of that in .bashrc. I guess it is just the updated version of that command.

Comment: Earlier I linked the wrong question. Did you try running `shopt -s direxpand`?